# Php multidimensional array html output

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, output

I want to create html output from array

But I could not completed the code. Are there any one who can complete.

Or are there any better idea to write this code?

```
$schema = array(
    0 => array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'lines',
        0 => array(
            'tag' => 'div',
            0 => array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'key' => 'Product Name'
            ),
            'val' => 'Soap'
        )
        1 => array(
            'tag' => 'div',
            0 => array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'key' => 'Product Name'
            ),
            'val' => 'Ball'
        )
    )
);

function get_output($schema){
    foreach($schema as $k => $v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $v = get_output($v);
        }else{
            $info = '<$tag $att>$key</$tag>';
            if($k == 'tag'){ $info = str_replace('$tag',$v,$info); }
            if($k == 'class'){ $info = str_replace('$att','"'.$v.'" $att',$info); }
        }
    }
    return $info;
}

echo get_output($schema);
```

Expected Output is

```
<div class="lines">
    <div><span>Product Name</span>Soap</div>
    <div><span>Pruduct Name</span>Ball</div>
</div><!-- #lines -->
```

---

UPDATE 1

Is it possible to create same function for following array..

```
$schema = array(
    'div' => array(
        'class' => 'lines',
        'div' => array(
             'span' => array(
                'key' => 'Product Name'
            ),
            'val' => 'Soap'
        ),
        'div' => array(
             'span' => array(
                'key' => 'Product Name'
            ),
            'val' => 'Ball'
            )
        )
);
```

UPDATE 2

What about that one?

```
$schema = array(
    'div' => array(
        'class' => 'lines',
        'div' => array(
             'span' => array(
                'key' => 'Product Name'
            ),
            'val' => 'Soap'
        ),
        'layer' => array(
             'span' => array(
                'key' => 'Product Name'
            ),
            'val' => 'Ball'
            )
        )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple recursive tree renderer can be implemented like this...

```
<?php

$schema = array(
array(
    'tag' => 'div',
    'class' => 'lines',
    array(
        'tag' => 'div',
         array(
            'tag' => 'span',
            'key' => 'Product Name'
        ),
        'val' => 'Soap'
    ),
     array(
        'tag' => 'div',
         array(
            'tag' => 'span',
            'key' => 'Product Name'
        ),
        'val' => 'Ball'
        )
    )
);

function get_output($schema){
    $tag = "";
    $attribs = array();
    $children = array();
    foreach($schema as $k => $v){        
        if(is_array($v)){
            $children[] = get_output($v);
        } else {
            switch($k){
                case "tag":
                    $tag = $v;
                    break;
                case "val":
                case "key":
                    $children[] = $v;
                    break;
                default:
                    $attribs[$k] = $v;
                    break;
            }
        }    
    }
    $str= "";
    if ($tag){
        $str = "<$tag";
        foreach($attribs as $k=>$v){
            $str.= " $k=\"".urlencode($v)."\"";
        }
        $str.= ">";
    }
    foreach($children as $child){
        $str.=$child;    
    }
    if ($tag){
        $str.= "</".$tag.">";
    }
    return $str;

}

echo get_output($schema);
```

Outputs

```
<div class="lines"><div><span>Product Name</span>Soap</div><div><span>Product Name</span>Ball</div></div>
```

To answer your updated question if duplicate sibling tags cannot happen then reimplementing your get_output function like:

```
function get_output($schema, $tag = false){
    $attribs = array();
    $children = array();
    foreach($schema as $k => $v){        
        if(is_array($v)){
            $children[] = get_output($v, $k);
        } else {
            switch($k){
                case "val":
                case "key":
                    $children[] = htmlspecialchars($v);
                    break;
                default:
                    $attribs[$k] = $v;
                    break;
            }
        }    
    }
    echo $tag; print_r($children); print_r($attribs);
    $str= "";
    if ($tag){
        $str = "<$tag";
        foreach($attribs as $k=>$v){
            $str.= " $k=\"".urlencode($v)."\"";
        }
        $str.= ">";
    }
    foreach($children as $child){
        $str.=$child;    
    }
    if ($tag){
        $str.= "</".$tag.">";
    }
    return $str;

}
```

Should get you where you need to be.

Comment: Orangepill this is lightening speed answer. This is perfect solution.. Is it possible to create same output from UPDATED array structure? With names

Comment: @DenizPorsuk Your array won't work in the updated example... there are two keys named div.

Comment: You are totally right. I changed the code. Could it be for UPDATE 2

Comment: I want to have smallest array as much as possible.

Comment: @DenizPorsuk Your first approach was the sanest. Given layer as an associative key how would one know that it's supposed to be a div?

Comment: Can't we use array names?

Comment: @DenizPorsuk Yes, but you would still have to designate the tag type, which would get you back to your orignal solution of having the tag type as another attribute for each node. So the net saving would be zero and you would incur the additional overhead of having to ensure your keys are unique.

Comment: You are right @Orangepill actually this function totally for this kind of problem.
I have repeated information in my website.
I will supply schema to the my function. This function will recognize the html structure and will output all variables if they are exist.
But because of repeated place is always same.. There will be never same tag structure.

Comment: I will write just
get_details("Builder=".get('b_builder')."&Location=".get('b_location'),$schema);

It will output like

<div class="lines">
 <div><span>Builder</span>$b_builder</div>
 <div><span>Location</span>$b_locatin</div>
</div><!-- #lines -->

Sure if location is empty result will be

<div class="lines">
 <div><span>Builder</span>$b_builder</div>
</div><!-- #lines -->

If both of them empty result will be empty also..

Comment: Thank you. Orangepill I just saw your second answer. You are really good programmer.